# Why this function get invoked exactly once

Tags: c++

I was reading `The C++ Programming Language 3rd edition`. In chapter 15(page 398), it presents a small example.

```
class Window {
public:
    virtual void draw() { //sth }
};
class Window_with_border : public virtual Window {
public:
    void own_draw() { //sth }
    void draw() {Window::draw(); own_draw();}
};
class Window_with_menu : public virtual Window {
public:
    void own_draw() { //sth }
    void draw() {Window::draw(); own_draw(); }
};
class Clock : public Window_with_border, public Window_with_menu {
public:
    void own_draw() { //sth }
    void draw() {Window::draw(); Window_with_border::draw(); Window_with_menu::draw(); own_draw(); }
};
```

Then the author says The `draw()` functions can now be written using the `own_draw()` functions so that a caller of any `draw()` gets `Window::draw()`invoked exactly once.

But i think, when you defines a Clock object and invoke the draw(), it gets invoked three times. Like this

```
Clock obj;
obj.draw() //The Window::draw() function got invoked three times?
```

Am i right?

Update: Sorry, i misread the code. The correct code is this：

```
class Clock : public Window_with_border, public Window_with_menu {
public:
    void own_draw() { //sth }
    void draw() {Window::draw(); Window_with_border::own_draw(); Window_with_menu::own_draw(); own_draw(); }
};
```

So i was wrong.

Comment: the problem you are encountering is the diamond problem.  look here: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/virtual_inheritance.html

Comment: `draw` is virtual (and `Window` was inherited as virtual -> included once in final Clock), thus `obj.draw()` calls Clock::draw, which explicitly calls the other draws NON-VIRTUALLY (conrete implementation).

Comment: @firda: `BaseClassName::function_name()` from virtual method is always non-virtual

Comment: On a side note, this is a prime example of terrible-use of inheritance and the author of said-book should be told not to use it as an example, and then promptly shot :)

Comment: @Moo-Juice: First of all, you do realise who is the author of that book, don't you? Second, who knows what techniques you are using today will be considered terrible in 20 years from now? Perhaps the programmer community as a whole will have discovered that lambdas and shared_ptrs are terrible.

Comment: @Moo-Juice … I really hope you are kidding about shooting the author… really hope…

Comment: @ChristianHackl, I know full well who the author is - and it still is a terrible example.  There are a few cases where you come across the diamond problem, and this example is surely not one of them.  Yes, things change over time (Singletons were the rage not so long ago, and although I feel they still have their place in fringe cases, you'll be shot to death for using them as an example on Stack Overflow)...  it's an iterative thing.  As it stands, today, that example is a terrible example. :)

Comment: @ i read and understand the article. But i still don't know how many times exactly the draw() function got invoked.

Comment: @Moo-Juice: The example is quite terrible, of course. My point was that judging the author of a book from 1997 by today's standards is unfair. You can criticise Stroustrup if this example is still present in current versions of his book; after all, he is still very actively involved in the evolution of C++ and should know better by now. However, even then your words would sound quite disrespectful when you consider Stroustrup's contribution to the world of software engineering as a whole.

Comment: @ChristianHackl, I don't dispute what you say one iota, I have a lot of respect for the man.  You're right that comparing examples from 1997 to today is "unfair".  However, here we are in 2014 and people are learning C++ from a book written in 1997.  Surely therefore it is fair to state it is a bad example, and as you rightly say, new programmers should be reading more up-to-date books, even by the same author. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Longer explanation***: That is excatly what the author is talking about - `Window::draw()` gets called three times:

1. Window::draw();
2. Window_with_border::draw();
3. Window_with_menu::draw();

You can ommit the first one and rewrite it like this:

```
class Clock : public Window_with_border, public Window_with_menu {
public:
    void own_draw() { //sth }
    void draw() {
        Window_with_border::draw();
        Window_with_menu::draw();
        own_draw(); }
};
```

But still twice, so the final should be:

```
class Clock : public Window_with_border, public Window_with_menu {
public:
    void own_draw() { //sth }
    void draw() {
        Window::draw();
        Window_with_border::own_draw();
        Window_with_menu::own_draw();
        own_draw(); }
};
```

OR:

```
class Clock : public Window_with_border, public Window_with_menu {
public:
    void own_draw() { //sth }
    void draw() {
        Window_with_border::draw();
        Window_with_menu::own_draw();
        own_draw(); }
};
```

Comment: Thanks! I just don't know what the author really want to say in this example.

Comment: I hope you got it now, it was a mess which draw where we talk about ;)